# Make WordPress site-title link redirect when user is already logged in

Tags: wordpress

I am currently testing a WordPress membership site. When the user is logged in they are redirected to www.example.com/courses/.

When the user is already logged in and active I would like that the site-title link (www.example.com) redirects to www.example.com/courses/

I have been looking at the hook wp_authenticate

Can someone send me in the right direction?

Thanks for all help

Answer (score 1):

you can use `is_user_logged_in()` Function to check if the user is logged in and `wp_redirect( $url ) to redirect the page.

```
if(is_user_logged_in()):
    wp_redirect( "www.example.com/courses" );
    exit;
endif;
```

Remember to exit after `wp_redirect()`

Comment: Yes, put this at the very start of your front-page template. Or if you can't modify it, use the `template_redirect` hook and check that `if(is_front_page()) { ... redirect  with the answer above ... }`